# Integrating an existing wcf project in Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I have a wcf application used in a website and i want to use it in my Silverlight application.
If i try to add it as a reference in silverlight application, vs gives an error that the application should be a silverlight application.
is there any way to use it? i don't want to write the wcf layer all over.
Thanks

Comment: Check this link it explains some options to solve this issue http://forums.silverlight.net/p/17733/74745.aspx#74745

Answer (score 0):

Add it as [service reference](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/wcf/a1647f10-9aa4-4b0c-bbd9-dfa51a9fab8e/adding-wcf-service-references.aspx).

Edit:

See this [forum thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/10909.aspx)

> Use the "Add Service Reference" function, it does effectively the same thing as the old familiar "Add Web Reference" used to do for other project types. :)

Comment: it's not .svc. it;s a service with channel factory.